# Agreement 2x2 table

Tags: r

I'm having trouble generating a 2x2 table with my data and was hoping to get some help. I can do this in excel but I really want to learn it in R. I'm trying to construct a 2x2 table for agreement where 1=yes and 2=no. A made a sample table below and sample data. Most of what I find online does not generate the table with two outcomes but instead it generates multiple descriptive variables with a label. I would appreciate the assistance.

|  | Yes | No |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Yes |  |  |
| :--- | :--: | --: |
| No |  |  |

| person1 | person2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 |

Comment: Try using `table()`. You can find more info in: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/table. If you want to display the NA values on it you should also have to set the `useNA` = "always" option. Also is recommended to set as factor variables as you want to do a contingency table with categories.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = read.table(text = 'person1  person2
1   1
1   0
1   1
0   0
0   1
0   0
1   1
1   1
0   1
0   0', header = T)

table(x)
#        person2
# person1 0 1
#       0 3 2
#       1 1 4
```